# Sentiment Analysis in R using TDM/DTM

Tags: r, text-mining, data-analysis, sentiment-analysis, sentimentr

I am trying to apply a sentiment analysis in R with the help of my DTM (document term matrix) or TDM (term document matrix). I could not find any similar topic in the forum and on google. Thus, I created a corpus and from that corpus I generated a dtm/tdm in R. My next step would be to apply the sentiment analysis which I need later for stock prediction via SVM. My give code is that:

```
    dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
    dtm <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.99)
    dtm <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm))

    tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
    tdm <- removeSparseTerms(tdm, 0.99)
    tdm <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(tdm))
```

I read that it is possible through the tidytext package with the help of the get_sentiments() function. But it was not possible to apply that with a DTM/TDM. How can I run a sentiment analysis for my cleaned filter words which are already stemmed, tokenized etc.? I saw that a lot of people did the sentiment analysis for a hole sentence, but I would like to apply it for my single words in order to see if they are positive, negative, score etc. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to convert your TDM to a data.frame and use `tidytext`? I see you did for the `dtm`, did it fail?

Comment: @NelsonGon my dtm and tdm are data.frames as you can see in my code. Or what do you mean?

Comment: What I meant was did you try to use them with `tidytext` and fail(ed) because you say `apply that with a DTM/TDM.`  which seemed to me that you were using a `tdm/dtm` class object hence my comment before I edited it?

Comment: Ahh I did not use tidytext yet. I created a corpus via the tm package and did my preprocessing also through the tm package. Now for the sentiment analysis, I wanted to start with tidytext. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SentimentAnalysis` has good integration with `tm`.

```
library(tm)
library(SentimentAnalysis)

documents <- c("Wow, I really like the new light sabers!",
               "That book was excellent.",
               "R is a fantastic language.",
               "The service in this restaurant was miserable.",
               "This is neither positive or negative.",
               "The waiter forget about my dessert -- what poor service!")

vc <- VCorpus(VectorSource(documents))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(vc)

analyzeSentiment(dtm, 
  rules=list(
    "SentimentLM"=list(
      ruleSentiment, loadDictionaryLM()
    ),
    "SentimentQDAP"=list(
      ruleSentiment, loadDictionaryQDAP()
    )
  )
)
#   SentimentLM SentimentQDAP
# 1       0.000     0.1428571
# 2       0.000     0.0000000
# 3       0.000     0.0000000
# 4       0.000     0.0000000
# 5       0.000     0.0000000
# 6      -0.125    -0.2500000
```

Comment: akselA thanks for your quick answer. If I try the analyzeSentiment() function I am getting this error: Error in !all.equal(dim(x), c(0, 0)) : invalid argument type

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example? Find a subset of your corpus that exhibits this behaviour, and share that using `dput()`.

Comment: bro! it worked! i found my problem. I converted my dtm to a dataframe/matrix. thats why the sentiment function was not working. Now I will try the functions of the tidytext with the nrc, bing etc lexicon! thanks a lot

Comment: I see. Looking at `?analyzeSentiment` the function should be able to handle a `data.frame`, so maybe something went wrong when you converted it?

Comment: I dont know. But for now it works well! So this are the sentiment scores based on lougran and qdap lexicon for the corpus sentence or the words?

Comment: Sentiment per document, but in my simple example that would mean per sentence. The package has a comprehensive [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SentimentAnalysis/vignettes/SentimentAnalysis.html) you might want to read through.

Answer (score 0):

To use tidytext on dtm to get sentiments convert dtm to tidy format first and then do inner join between tidy data and dictionary of polarised words.I will use the same document as used above. Some doc in above example are positive but given neutrel score.
let's see how tidytext performs

```
library(tidytext)
library(tm)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

documents <- c("Wow I really like the new light sabers",
           "That book was excellent",
           "R is a fantastic language",
           "The service in this restaurant was miserable",
           "This is neither positive or negative",
           "The waiter forget about my dessert -- what poor service")

# create tidy format
vectors <- as.character(documents)
v_source <- VectorSource(vectors)
corpuss <- VCorpus(v_source)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpuss)
as_tidy <- tidy(dtm)

# Using bing lexicon: you can use other as well(nrc/afinn)
bing <- get_sentiments("bing")
as_bing_words <- inner_join(as_tidy,bing,by = c("term"="word"))
# check positive and negative words 
as_bing_words  

# set index for documents number 
index <- as_bing_words%>%mutate(doc=as.numeric(document))
# count by index and sentiment
index <- index %>% count(sentiment,doc)
# spread into positives and negavtives
index <- index %>% spread(sentiment,n,fill=0)
# add polarity scorer
index <- index %>% mutate(polarity = positive-negative)
index
```

[image]

Doc 4 and 6 are negative,5 neutrel and rest positive which is actually the case